# Why can't i import my component from the same folder?

Tags: reactjs, image, import, directory

I'm importing my icons to my BtnSlider.js, is there anything wrong but there's a mistake as "*./src/components/Slider/BtnSlider.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './Icons/left-arrow.png' in 'C:\Users\Admow.png*'"

This is my BtnSlider:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Slider.css";
import leftArrow from "./Icons/left-arrow.png";
import rightArrow from "./Icons/right-arrow.jpg";

export default function BtnSlider() {
  return (
    <button className="btn-slide">
      <img src={rightArrow} />{" "}
    </button>
  );
}
```

This is my directory:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your directory structure is different than you think.

[image]

You have a file named `Icons` in the same directory as your images. But you seem to be expecting `Icons` to be a directory, and your images to be inside that.

To fix it it you can either create the correct directory structure, or change your imports to:

```
import leftArrow from "./left-arrow.png";
```

Comment: yah i created another folder and it works! thank you!